# Should (can) we standardise bibliographic references?

Tags: feature-request, references

In addition to [Gpierce's](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12/gpierce) [question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-include-sources-in-answers), should we standardise the way that bibliographic references are formatted?

It has been a while since I wrote a bibliography, so for my last [answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-led-to-the-first-fight-in-the-american-civil-war/69#69) I had to look up how they should be formatted. I wonder if this can be built into the editor for this site? Should I be referencing Google Books in the link? Is there a more authoritative source?

Comment: What is the advantage of a formal bibliography over setting hyperlinks on the relevant text passages? We are not going to print our answers on dead trees...

Answer (score 3):

I think that might be a bit more formal than necessary. If you want to do a standard reference, than by all means do so, but I think the title of the work and a link if online or just the author if not online would be fine too. I think requiring a bibliographic reference is kind of formal for the idea of the QA system.